# How to include kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath

Tags: kotlin, gradle, reflection, kotlin-reflect

I am trying to call `someObject::class.annotations` but get an error in runtime:

`Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath`

I tried including the reflection library inside my `build.gradle.kts` file in any of the different forms suggested on StackOverflow and am still getting this error!

In the `dependencies` block inside the gradle file I tried:

```
api(kotlin("reflect"))
runtimeOnly(kotlin("reflect"))
implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.0")
```

Yet none of these solve the issue and there is no official documentation on how to include this jar inside the classpath.

Comment: please attach the command used to run your executable jar